# Alternating, Telescoping series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

I know the definitions and tests for convergence,  my question deals with an alternating series which converge on a range. For example, we can consider the sum of the alternating harmonic series:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} =1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{5} \dots =\ln2
$$
Now, suppose we were to modify this series, into one which does not converge on a single value, but alternates between two values, to both of which it converges on each sign change. For example,
We change the above mentioned series in the following way:

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{n} =\dfrac{2}{1}-\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{4}{3} - \dfrac{5}{4} \dots
$$

This series does not converge according to the traditional definition of convergence I guess, failure to converge on a single value is considered divergence- and I know that,  but it does alternate between two values on which it seems to converge, those values **seem** to be (just by looking at the partial sums):
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 
    \begin{cases}
        \ln2 &\quad \text{if} \quad n \mod2 \equiv 0 \\
        \ln2 + 1 &\quad \text{if} \quad n \mod2 \equiv 1\\ 
     \end{cases}
$$

My question is, is there some framework to study these kinds of series? Even though the series does not converge on a point, it is still kind of cool if we might be able to say that both of its branches are convergent with a definite value between them

Comment: Your notion of alternating between two different values isn't really clear. Do you mean subsequences of the sequence of partial sums?

Comment: Yes, meaning that for all even values of n, it converges on one limit, and all odd values on another limit.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer forgot the tag

Comment: Are you sure that those series converge, then? Each series (those of the positive terms, and those of the negative terms) end up having their terms converge to $\pm 1$ (not $0$), and thus the series each diverge.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I have written a program to find the first million terms of this series, the millionth term is within $10^{-5}$  from $\ln2$. The 999,999th is within the same distance from $\ln2 +1$

Comment: I'd be happy to share the code so you can see it, if you use R that is.

Comment: Then something is simply wrong with the program, or we're not on the same page. (I don't know anything about R though.) After all, if $n$ is even, then $(-1)^{n+1} = -1$ and

$$\frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = - \frac{n+1}{n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} -1$$

Likewise, if $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^{n+1} = 1$ and

$$\frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{n} =   \frac{n+1}{n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$

And, as we know, a necessary condition (but not sufficient) for the convergence of $\sum a_n$ is that $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: This is also easily seen in Wolfram. Taking the first $100$ terms with $n=2k$, we have that the sum is about $-102.59$ ([Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+100+%28%282k%29%2B1%29+%28-1%29%5E%28%282k%29%2B1%29+%2F+%282k%29)). Meanwhile, taking the same situation for $n=2k+1$ instead, we have the sum equal to about $102.29$ instead ([Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+100+%28%282k%2B1%29%2B1%29+%28-1%29%5E%28%282k%2B1%29%2B1%29+%2F+%282k%2B1%29)).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I was talking about the 2 limits for the sequence of partial sums... you mixed my explanation of the way it converges, with the actual series... you can try and run the sum as is on wolfram alpha, i doubt it will give you 1m terms but its all I can say.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer let wolfram run this **exactly**:  "sum((n+1)*(-1)**(n+1)/(n))"

Comment: Oh okay, I think you see what you're meaning now. Basically, there are two subsequences of the sequence

$$s_N := \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

and the subsequence for $N$ odd (i.e. $s_1,s_3,s_5,\cdots$) converges seemingly to $\ln 2 + 1$, and the subsequence for $N$ even  (i.e. $s_2,s_4,s_6,\cdots$) converges seemingly to $\ln 2$. And this phenomenon is what your question is fundamentally what this question is about?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer yes, whether there is any framework to evaluate a series like this, considering both individual values converge, and so their difference should also converge.

Comment: look at wiki entry on [divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series), in particular those sections about summation methods.